# How to define Body Size in Report Viewer ? (Visual studio 2010)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, reportviewer

I create Report Viewer in my ASP.net project(.rdlc file) and I have problem when I export it to PDF.(I got extra blank page for every page).
I read a solution that I have to change the Body Size. `Body ->Properties -> Size ..`,
but I can't find size in Body Properties. That's the option I have there: (only `Fill` and `Border`)

[image: Here is a picture]

Where can I change the body size?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

You can set *Body size* by left-clicking on body area and pressing F4.

You also have to set *Report Size* and *Margins* by right-clicking outside your report (grey area).

Note that *Report size* include *Margins* so you have to set *Body size* according to this; i.e. `Body.Width = Report.Width - Report.Margins.Right - Report.Margins.Left`